# Renaming a Folder in my file browser causes IOException

Tags: browser, rename, ioexception, filesystemwatcher

The Project is a backup program.

I have two browsers side by side in the same form (two TreeViews and two ListViews), the left one displays source files and the right one displays backed up files, but when they are not browsing a backup they can be used as dual file browsers.
As Nodes are visited in the treeview a FileSystemWatcher (which doesn't watch subdirectories) is added to that folder. I can rename Files and folders in the listview and using windows explorer, the changes are reflected in both, even if the folder is selected in the treeview the rename happens fine. As soon as I select a folder inside of the folder to be renamed and then select a folder outside of the folder, neither the listview nor Win Explorer can rename the folder anymore, it produces an IOException.

The ex.ToString reads (dfgdotttd is just from me trying to rename the folder many times):

System.IO.IOException: Access to the path 'D:\Visual Basic Projects\BackUp\BackUp_01\INIT\New folder\dfgdotttd' is denied.
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalMove(String sourceDirName, String destDirName, Boolean checkHost)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.RenameDirectory(String directory, String newName)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices.FileSystemProxy.RenameDirectory(String directory, String newName)
   at BackUp.Ute.ReNameDir(String OldDir, String NewDirName, Boolean Notify)

OldDir is 'Path and name' of the folder and NewDirName is just the 'new name'.

When I try the rename in Win Explorer the Windows dialog reads:

"Folder In Use" 
The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program
Close the folder or file and try again.

The only way I can fix it is to close the browser and reopen it.

Adding FSW's to a list(of FilesystemWatcher), which is initiated in either TreeViews AfterSelect event.

TreeView AfterSelect:

```
If Not Visited_Nodes_A.Contains(HOSTNode.Name) Then 'Collection of visited nodes for TVA
   Visited_Nodes_A.Add(HOSTNode.Name)
   If Not Visited_Nodes_B.Contains(HOSTNode.Name) Then 'Collection of visited nodes for TVB
       AddWatcher(HOSTNode.Name) 'If folder was visited in other TreeView THEN a Watcher would already have been added.
   End If
End If 'Not Visited_Nodes_A.Contains(HOSTNode.Name)
```

Adding the FSWs'

```
        Private FileWatchers As New List(Of FileSystemWatcher)
Public Sub AddWatcher(WPath As String, Optional Subffolders As Boolean = False) 'Add new watcher to a newly visited folder
    Dim fsw As New FileSystemWatcher()
    fsw.Path = WPath
    fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = Subffolders
    AddHandler fsw.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler fsw.Created, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler fsw.Deleted, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler fsw.Renamed, AddressOf OnRenamed : AddHandler fsw.Renamed, AddressOf OnChanged
    fsw.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters.FileName Or NotifyFilters.DirectoryName)
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    FileWatchers.Add(fsw)
End Sub 'AddWatcher
```

I would show the OnChanged Sub but it doesn't get that far

I guess this is not much to go on but I am teaching myself from Google etc and it's a bit like banging my head on a wall sometimes but I have time on my hands. Perhaps someone here can spot something obvious :)

Comment: You will need to remove the FSWs which are looking at the subdirectories of the directory you want to rename - they are the entities which have the folders open.